# Help with determining model for cross-sectional data where all variables are dummies

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, interaction, cross-section

I am currently working on my dissertation project where my data are essentially all dummies. From my dependent to my independent variables, everything is a dummy variable (0,1), at least for the preliminary model. The data are cross-sectional.

I was wondering what the best model to use would be. I have decided to do a simple regression followed by logit and probit. Does that sounds like it covers everything? I have some interaction terms too. Also, what tests I can use?

Comment: Thank you. That was all the confirmation I required. Thanks very much!

Comment: Fair enough, I'll make it an official answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion doesn't make sense.  If your response variable is 0/1, then you should use logistic regression or probit.  (If you want help understanding the distinction between them, it may help you to read my answer here: [Difference between logit and probit models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30909/7290).)  You can include interactions as you like.  The model output will come with Wald tests of the parameters without your having to do anything else.